# How to store the access token for Spotify api. I am using passport.js

Tags: node.js, passport.js, access-token

I am using passport.js to authenticate to Spotify api, I am logging in correctly, no problem with that.

But now I want to store the access token or display something in console that gives back some information about the user so I can use the access token to create playlist. How can I store the access token?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to store the Spotify API Access Token so it can be re-used across sessions.

If I'm correct, you should be able to write the token to a file.

```
const fs = require('fs');
// passport.js stuff here
fs.writeFile('./.spotify-token', '< the access token >', (err) => {
    if (err) throw new Error('Failed to write ./.spotify-token: ' + err);
});
```

And it can be read like this:

```
const token = fs.readFileSync('./.spotify-token'); // => String (the token) or throws an error
```

With this, you can feed the token back into Passport.